# Are there limitations in mysqli that make it unsuitable for use with AMP or ReactPHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, reactphp, amphp

I've seen that libraries such as [amphp/mysql](https://github.com/amphp/mysql) and [friends-of-reactphp/mysql](https://github.com/friends-of-reactphp/mysql) implement the low-level MySQL protocol, and do not rely on any built-in extension.

Given that [mysqli supports async queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.reap-async-query.php), is there any reason why these async libraries cannot be based on `mysqli`?

<sub>*Originally asked as [Why isn't amphp/mysql based on mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59443815/759866) (closed).*</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey ReactPHP core team member here. In short you shouldn't use them (you always can but we strongly advise against it) because their I/O isn't hooked into our event loop. Meaning it can block the entire loop and everything hooked into it until it's done with what ever it does.

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much the answer I got from AMP, too!

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy [@bwoebi](https://github.com/bwoebi) [on `amphp/mysql`'s GitHub](https://github.com/amphp/mysql/issues/94):

> `mysqli_poll()` is just polling... `mysql`. It does not provide you any possibility to poll any other streams together with the mysql data.
>   There's no underlying file descriptors exposed by mysqli which the event loop could use.